# Datasets for Activity Detection from images

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, images

I'm searching for some datasets to implement a Human Activity Recognition model I can use on images/videos. Most of the datasets seem to be using sensory data obtained through an accelerometer along with other parameters. I would like to know if there are any image datasets for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following links include various resources related to your search:

- [Action Databases](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/Imagedbase.htm#action): this a list of various datasets of images, videos performing basic actions along with their labels
- [Kinetics](https://deepmind.com/research/open-source/kinetics)  collection of large-scale, high-quality datasets of URL links of up to 650,000 video clips that cover 400/600/700 human action classes.